# What is the passport validity period requirement for a Kuwait employment visa?

Tags: passports, visa-expiration, working-visas, kuwait

My passport is going to expire on 30 July 2020, and I have a job opportunity coming up in Kuwait. Will I be eligible to get this visa, which is for a 2-year contract?

Comment: Your nationality?

Answer (score 2):

You will first get a normal visa (business visit) which will allow you to enter the country. Once you are landed, the company will then transfer you to the work visa category.

To get the initial visa, you just need to have a valid passport - for that, your passport's expiry is okay.

During the transfer process, the company will stamp your work visa. The regulation states that the visa duration cannot be more than the passport duration. Most likely the company will stamp you a 1 year visa, then renew it for the second year.

You must renew your passport before you can renew the visa - and you can approach your local embassy or representative mission in Kuwait to handle that formality.